# Raspberry PiFace, need to put 14 gauge wire in 1.5mm terminal

Tags: raspberry-pi, wire, terminal, wire-terminals

I have a PiFace and I need to get at 14 gauge wire which is 1.63mm thick into a 1.5mm screw terminal. To pass 4 Amps at 24VDC. I only have 14 gauge and 22 gauge wire, the 22 gauge wire won't pass all the current I need. So, are there any ideas on how to connect this... File the wire, etc.

Comment: What are you using it for? 22AWG is rated for 7 Amps for chassis wiring.  For power transmission, it is only rated at 0.92A, but in almost all cases of breadboarding, you don't need to worry about the transmission rating.  For the record, 22AWG should be about 0.0128 ohms per foot.

Comment: AWG22 is fine for 4A under most conditions. If you need to run fatter wire because of voltage drop, then just splice to the thinner wire near the terminal block (and cover the splice with some shrink wrap to keep it neat).

Comment: Shell out a few bucks for the right size wire...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this table: https://wiki.xtronics.com/index.php/Wire-Gauge_Ampacity

It lists a source for the table and clearly states that the ampacity for free air is 7 amps. Free air means the wire is literally suspended in open air and not inside a raceway or enclosure. Inside of an enclosure or raceway, the maximum is 5 amps. BUT, remember that rating is limited by the thermal ability of the insulation. If you bundle multiple conductors all carrying a lot of current their combined heat output will add up. This the temperature up and can easily exceed the temperature rating of the insulation. So two wires carrying 4 amps might be fine. Eight bundled together might melt and/or become a fire hazard.